# (Javascript) Clarification on "this" within an array literal

Tags: javascript, arrays, literals

```
var RPGConfig = (function() {
    var Constructor = function() {
        this.dir = "js";
        this.enginedir = "js/Engine";
    };
    Constructor.prototype = {
        include: [
            this.dir + "/Common.js",
            this.dir + "/Common/Class.js"
        ],
        test: function() {
            alert(this.dir);
        }
    };
    return Constructor;
})();
rpgConfig = new RPGConfig();
rpgConfig.test();
console.log(rpgConfig.include);
```

So, if I run rpgConfig.test(), the alert pops up with "js". Great! But, my rpgConfig.include shows up with "undefined" where this.dir should have printed "js" (as it did in test())...

So, how do I add "this" scope into an array literal?

Thanks

Comment: See also [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/1048572)

Comment: Array and object literals don't have a scope. They're just inside a function scope, which is responsible for the `this` value - in this case your module IEFE. You'll have to move it inside your constructor.

Comment: Perfect comments @Bergi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply can't, because prototype is made to "share" members between every instance of a class (and its descendency if never overridden). Which means you have to wrap it in a function for it to give you what you need.

```
Constructor.prototype = {
    include: function () {
        return [
            this.dir + "/Common.js",
            this.dir + "/Common/Class.js"
        ];
    },
    test: function() {
        alert(this.dir);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignment to `Constructor.prototype` is evaluated first, before the constructor function. At the time it is evaluated, the constructor function has been declared, but not run, so the value of `this.dir` is undefined at that time.

The reason the `test()` function works is because it grabs the value of `this.dir` on demand every time you call it, so by the time you call it, `this.dir` has already been assigned.